# What can we say about the pronunciation of Z?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, loanwords

The letter Z was borrowed into the Latin alphabet in order to transcribe Greek loanwords, along with Y.

Presumably, educated Latin-speakers pronounced it like its source, Greek zeta. However, Greek zeta had various different pronunciations across time periods and dialects.

What can we say about the Latin pronunciation of Z in loanwords? Do any ancient grammarians comment on this, for example? Or can transcriptions of Greek words into other languages confirm its pronunciation at that time?

Comment: Maybe you’ll find something useful here https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/6751/39

Comment: Question inspired by [this comment](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16387/what-does-a-vowel-followed-by-two-consonants-exactly-mean/16388?noredirect=1#comment34130_16388), which made me realize we have some related questions but no question about this specifically.

Answer (score 8):

Two reasons for thinking that Z was pronounced in Latin as a fricative:

- The spelling SS was once used to represent it, as you mention in your prior question [When did the Romans start using Z?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6774/when-did-the-romans-start-using-z)
- The spelling "ZM" existed as a variant for "SM" in words from Greek with ΣΜ. Since Σ is not thought to have been pronounced as an affricate in Greek, presumably, these words with ZM spellings weren't pronounced with an affricate in Latin either, but with a fricative.
  [Phi Examples](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=zm) (e.g. *Zmyrna, zmaragdos*)

Both of these are consistent with a pronunciation of zeta as either [z(ː)] or [s(ː)]

On the other hand, the use of Z as an alternative for DI in some inscriptions can be seen as evidence that Z could potentially represent an affricate.